# Image compresses in portrait or landscape view in c# windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have an image in a grid layout but on comparing the actual image with the image on emulator, it comes out that the image on emulator has compressed to fit into the image .How can this be avoided so that the image retains its actual resolution and aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the aspect ratio of your source, set the Image.Stretch property to Uniform.